# Sample of Chrome Native Messaging manifest V3

Tags: c#, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-native-messaging

Do you have any example on the below task I need to implement

1. I have an exe written in c#. This exe is will return data in json string
2. I have a web application, web application will run the exe through chrome extension native messaging manifest v3
3. Chrome extension will get the response from exe and will populate it on the web application

I'm not able to search sample to build it in manifest V3, some of the samples I've seen is using manifest v2 which is using clipboard.

Comment: Here are C https://github.com/guest271314/NativeMessagingHosts/blob/main/nm_c.c and C++ https://github.com/guest271314/NativeMessagingHosts/blob/main/nm_cpp.cpp versions of a Native Messaging host. I have no experience using C#, though there are C# Native Messaging hosts on GitHub.